# When do we double the last letter in the past tense?

Tags: past-tense

When do we double the last letter in the past tense?
Is there any rule for that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm just citing:

When the verb ends in **consonant + vowel + consonant**, you have to double the last consonant  and then add "ed" to make the Past Simple.

> e.g. plan > *pla**nn**ed*

(Because: **l**= *consonant*. **a**= *vowel*. **n**=*consonant*)

- If you have a verb with more than one *syllable*, you only double the consonant if the last syllable is stressed.

> e.g. re'fer > refe**rr**ed

- In British English the final "l" is doubled, even if the last syllable is not stressed.

> e.g. travel > trav**ell**ed

- If the last letter is "x", you do not double it (because an "x" is in fact two consonant "ks".

> e.g.  fix > fixed

- If the last letter is "c", you write "ck" instead of "cc".)

> e.g. picnic > picni**ck**ed

- If the stress is not on the last syllable, don't double

  > e.g. de'velop  > developed

Of course these rules only apply to *regular verbs*.

For more information and examples [see here - the source of the citing that mentioned above](http://jottings.over-blog.com/article-past-simple-doubling-of-final-consonants-57062802.html).